# ExUnit without assert/refute, relying solely on pattern matching?

Tags: testing, elixir, ex-unit

I'm testing the return value of a function. Which of the two is the preferred way?

```elixir
test "extra verbose, using assert" do
  {:error, reason} = MyModule.my_fun
  assert reason == :nope
end

test "using pattern matching only" do
  {:error, :nope} = MyModule.my_fun
end
```

I like the first one because, I don't now, a test needs an `assert` statement and the error message when running the test is more descriptive. Otoh, a `MatchError` with line number should also be enough.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use `assert` with `=` to get both an `assert` and a more descriptive error message, and with just one line of code:

```
assert {:error, :nope} = MyModule.my_fun
```

Unlike with `==`, you can use any pattern on the LHS, although in this case, `=` can be replaced with `==` since the LHS is both a valid pattern and value.

On failure, you'll get an error message that's better than just doing the pattern matching without the `assert`, e.g.

```
  1) test the truth (MTest)
     test/m_test.exs:10
     match (=) failed
     code:  {:error, :nope} = MyModule.my_fun()
     right: {:error, :nop}
     stacktrace:
       test/m_test.exs:11: (test)
```

Comment: For me the main drawback to using assert on a match is you won't get the left vs right comparison in the test results

Comment: Is `assert {:error, :nope} = MyModule.my_fun` really testing anything? If the pattern matches, it will basically assert that the tuple `{:error, :nope}` is truthy, no? If the pattern doesn't match, there's still the `MatchError`.

Comment: @carp nope, there will not be any `MatchError`. `assert` handles `=` specially. I added an example test failure output to the answer just now.

Comment: @Stuart yes, if the LHS is a valid value, I'd use `==` to get that nice colored diff, but if it's not a valid value, this is better than doing just `pattern = value` in the test.

Comment: @Dogbert very true, I guess when asserting atom results the `==` isn't really necessary. Bottom line is always use an assert :)

Answer (score 1):

Whoever comes around this in 2022: consider always using `assert`, even in conjunction of pattern matching, e.g.:

```
assert {:error, :nope} = MyModule.my_fun()
```

Since 1.10, Elixir supports rendering colored diff when pattern matching fails:
https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/commit/98c6bba436cc4833363295e5fedd3f819504d79d